# Is there a tidyverse method to match and return the closest date from one table using another reference table

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way to match the closest date from one table with another table. Ive been trying to use tidyverse methods but havent been able to solve this.

I currently have a table (a) like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
 Selection Date      
 <chr>     <date>        
1 Premium   2020-11-11  
2 Classic   2020-12-09
3 Premium   2021-01-19
4 Classic   2021-05-10
5 Classic   2021-06-03
6 Classic   2021-06-15
```

And a reference date table (b):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  reference_date
  <date>         
1 2020-10-16    
2 2021-02-25    
3 2020-06-26    
4 2020-12-17    
5 2021-08-12    
6 2021-04-29
```

What im trying to do is match table (a) with table (b) so that based on the Date column I can find the "closest" reference_date; where the Date is always after the reference_date. Ideally im hoping the final result will be like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Selection Date        reference_date
  <chr>     <date>       <date> 
1 Premium   2020-11-11  2020-10-16 
2 Classic   2020-12-09  2020-10-16
3 Standout  2021-01-19  2020-12-17
4 Classic   2021-05-10  2021-08-12
5 Classic   2021-06-03  2021-08-12
6 Classic   2020-06-27  2020-06-26
```

Apologies if this question has already been asked but i couldnt find an answer to it and would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows is your real data?

Comment: Either your expected output is wrong or you need to be clearer about constraints: `"2020-12-09"` is closer to `"2020-12-17"` than it is to `"2020-10-16"`. Similarly, other rows are off, too.

Comment: Would you mind using `data.table` ? The question can then easily be answered with "nearest" rolling join

Comment: FYI @Waldi, I was working on it (the second half of my answer) when your comment appeared. I'm not stealing your excellent ideas.

Comment: @r2evans, glad you did answer also with `data.table`

Comment: As i have many rows in my data i've tried using the `data.table` method but i was only able to return a reference date that matched the actual purchase "Date". where the "Date" fell outside of the reference date it returned a `NA`. Any suggestions of where i went wrong.

Comment: And thank you for the assistance. For my constraints the reference dates represents price change dates and the "Date" column in table A are purchase dates so im trying to identify which price change group that a purchased product would fall into. So if a product was purchased on "2020-11-11" and we had changed prices on "2020-10-16" then that product would fall in that price change group. so the reference date can  provide information on what price change group i should assign a particular purchase date to. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

### base R

One method is to do an `outer` cartesian difference between the dates. This will not work if you have 'lots' of rows.

```r
outer(A$Date, B$reference_date, `-`)
# Time differences in days
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]   26 -106  138  -36 -274 -169
# [2,]   54  -78  166   -8 -246 -141
# [3,]   95  -37  207   33 -205 -100
# [4,]  206   74  318  144  -94   11
# [5,]  230   98  342  168  -70   35
# [6,]  242  110  354  180  -58   47

A$reference_date <- B[apply(abs(outer(A$Date, B$reference_date, `-`)), 1, which.min),]
A
#   Selection       Date reference_date
# 1   Premium 2020-11-11     2020-10-16
# 2   Classic 2020-12-09     2020-12-17
# 3   Premium 2021-01-19     2020-12-17
# 4   Classic 2021-05-10     2021-04-29
# 5   Classic 2021-06-03     2021-04-29
# 6   Classic 2021-06-15     2021-04-29

with(A, Date - reference_date)
# Time differences in days
# [1] 26 -8 33 11 35 47
```

### data.table and rolling joins

An alternative:

```r
library(data.table)
ADT <- as.data.table(A)
BDT <- as.data.table(B)

ADT[BDT, reference_date := i.reference_date, on = .(Date = reference_date), roll = TRUE]
#    Selection       Date reference_date
#       <char>     <Date>         <Date>
# 1:   Premium 2020-11-11     2020-10-16
# 2:   Classic 2020-12-09     2020-12-17
# 3:   Premium 2021-01-19     2021-04-29
# 4:   Classic 2021-05-10     2021-04-29
# 5:   Classic 2021-06-03     2021-04-29
# 6:   Classic 2021-06-15     2021-08-12
```